# Is there any library out there for c# that has the equivalent to "Unpack" in PHP and what is "Unpack"

Tags: c#, php

I just want to convert a piece of PHP code to C# so I need it's equivalent.

And what does unpack really do? I'm very interested in this function.

Comment: Have you read the documentation about pack and unpack in PHP? Please be more specific if you don't understand something from this doc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack reads the binary data according to the data type you tell it to parse as and returns the values in an array.

The closest thing I can think to this would be to a `struct` within C(++) / C#, where it populates the `struct`'s members with information from the binary data. A struct within C style languages is like an object, but without methods.

I can't think of any good examples right now on how to read data into a struct, but that's because I'm not really very good at C or C++ or C# for that matter. Try looking at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ReadingStructures.aspx) for examples on how to read data into structs ... or as always ... [google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=reading+a+packet+of+data+into+a+struct).

Comment: Here's an implementation for C, http://asgaard.homelinux.org/svn/rotekopp/pickle.c , you'd call it like depickle(buf,"SLS",&mystruct.foo,&mystruct.bar,&mystruct.othherfoo);(though only integer support so far)

Comment: I tend to agree with you @Jonathan, but I also think that's due to the fact that its the only way I really handle reading data in to struct. (In the packet based system that I read from.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function unpack(str As String) As String

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rstStr As String = ""
    For x = 0 To str.Length - 1
        rstStr &= Convert.ToString(Asc(str.Substring(x, 1)), 16)
    Next

    Return rstStr
End Function
```